# F# Fractal - a bug I can't figure out

Tags: f#, functional-programming, fractals

I'm trying to make an example I've found on the net work. It's a 3D fractal in F#. Here it is: http://tomasp.net/blog/infinite-cheese.aspx. The source code is available for download at the end of the article. The article and the sample were written in 2007, so I think the code is just slightly obsolete. There is one block of code that causes error and the code won't compile:

```
// Returns a cube with filtered sides
let private get_cube(incl_sides) =
    [ for (side,trigs) in cube
        when Set.mem side incl_sides
        ->> trigs ]
```

The `when` keyword is underlined, and the error message goes as follows:

> Unexpected keyword 'when' in expression. Expected '->' or other token.

I can't figure out what's wrong with this. In an attempt to understand the code better, I searched the langauge specs. As far as I know, there is nothing about the `Set.mem` function or the `->>` operator. Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[for (side, trigs) in cube do
    if Set.contains side incl_sides then
        yield! trigs]
```

The language has undergone a lot of changes since that code was written.  In particular, the `->>` operator has been replaced by `yield!`, `Set.mem` has been renamed to the more descriptive `Set.contains`, and comprehensions now use `if ... then` instead of `when`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the version of the source code that is linked from the blog post is a bit old. You can find the latest (updated) version in the [F# samples project](http://fsharpsamples.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/75020ae7cce3#Samples/FSharpFractal3D/Fractal.fs) on CodePlex. I think there may be some other changes, so it is best to get the version from CodePlex. (It includes `FractalSimple.fs` which is simpler version and `Fractal.fs` which also removes cube sides that are not visible).

The project contains standard Visual Studio 2008/2010 `.fsproj` project. The original version on the blog was written using F# CTP (from VS 2005 times) which had a completely different Visual Studio integration and used an obsolete `.fsharpp` project format (before MSBUILD format existed).

The `when` and `->>` constructs have been used as a lightweight syntax for writing queries, but are now deprecated, to keep the syntax inside comprehensions consistent with the rest of the language. As kvb points out, you can use ordinary `if .. then` and the only non-standard thing is `yield!`, which means *return all elements of the given sequence*.

Comment: Wow you are the author of the program. Thank you so much. I sent you an email with this question yesterday, guess you didn't get it. Or maybe there were issues with language barrier, I wrote it in Slovak :-) This might be presumptious of me, but I'm actually in dire need of help. Would it be possible for me to somehow contact you directly and discuss this?

Comment: Ok I actually get more bugs with the newer version. First thing that was missing were module names. then there's duplicate definition of 'cube'. And the more serious ones: Array.to_list,  Set.of_seq and List.fold_left2 are not defined.

Comment: @moebius: You're right - even the CodePlex version wasn't that up-to-date. I fiexed it and added VS 2010 project that should work with the latest F#. (The functions were slightly renamed, so e.g. `to_list` became `toList`).

Comment: @moebius: I got your email - I didn't even notice it was in Slovak :-). I can read Slovak just fine. I'm just slow at replying to emails... If you need some more help, feel free to send me email (I believe I answered everything here), or ask at Stackoverflow (where more people can help & usually help pretty fast :-)).

Comment: Hi, I've sent you another email. I know now that you are slow at replying to them, and I don't want to pressure you or anything. I'd just really like to know what you think about what I wrote in the email.